# M-x occur freezes for regexp

Tags: regex, emacs

Just tried to `M-x occur` with `[^*]*` and Emacs seems to hang. Can only be interrupted with `C-g`. Is this my fault?

Also `[^*][*]` freezes.

Comment: This isn't a programming question (unless you're the programmer of the Emacs regular expression code, and trying to fix this). It should probably be in superuser.com or the beta emacs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: All lines will match the first regular expression. `*` matches zero or more matches of the preceding regexp, and every line has at least zero non-asterisk characters.

Comment: Interesting, it only hangs if there's a line that actually contains `*`. It looks like some kind of infinite backtracking problem that occurs when it sees the `*` character.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the second regexp. But I'm using a pretty old version of Emacs, 22.3.1.

Comment: It would be better to report this as an Emacs bug, with `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: The `*` is a red-herring. It's freezing on `X*` for any `X`. I suspect it's attempting to capture infinity zero-width matches (never progressing to the next character from the previous match).

Comment: @phils: But my 2nd expression is just two characters

Comment: false: An excellent point, except (like Barmar) I can't reproduce that one (in either Emacs 24.3.1 or a recent unstable build). Which is also interesting, because Barmar is running a *very* old version. What is your version? Perhaps that particular bug was introduced and then fixed again somewhere inbetween...

Comment: @phils: 23.3.1 (blush)